# How to I append a LD_LIBRARY_PATH to bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path, centos

I'm trying to configure this python package called project, one of the last installation steps requires me to install the libsdf library which I did without issue.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd)/project/external/pysdf/build/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

cd ./project/external/pysdf/

python setup.py install
```

I can then call my project .py scripts which use libsdf with no issue as long as I run them through the terminal. Whenever I try to run the same script which worked in a terminal, through an IDE such as VScode, spyder or jupyter I get this error 'Error importing pysdf. Make sure `libsdf.so` is in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and pysdf is installed'. I'm guessing this is because I haven't defined LD_LIBRARY_PATH globally through the .bashrc.

I tried to correct this but I'm unsure how the LD_LIBRARY_PATH should look as I cant get it working.

I've tried the following:

```
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u/myusrname/code/projectv15/project/external/pysdf/build/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}' >> ~/.bashrc
```

where I used the absolute path to `/pysdf/build/` where `libsdf.so` is found.

Can anyone tell me how I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in bash correctly.

Comment: The problem is $pwd is being evaluated once when bash starts. Better is to install your library in a path searched by the system, or run it with the absolute path.

Comment: @Zizi96: While it is a bit odd that you modify a program by using `echo ... >>` instead of just using a text editor, I don't see anything wrong with your approach, provided that `/u/myusrname/code/projectv15/project/external/pysdf/build` is **really** the directory where your shared library is stored. Hence, after you start a new interactive bash shell, you should see the change in your environment. The only point is that I would **add** the new path only if LD_LIBRARY_PATH is already set, and afterwise set the variable from fresh.

Comment: @Zizi96 : Don't forget that .bashrc is only sourced by **interactive** bash scripts. I can't tell form your posting whether an interactive bash is started from your IDE.

Comment: @stark Am I not runnining the library with an absolute path with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u/myusrname/code/projectv15/project/external/pysdf/build/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}` ? The shared library libsdf.so is found in the /build folder

Comment: @user1934428 Double checked and I can confirm that the path you mentioned is where the libsdf.so is stored. I'm not sure about the interactive bash script from IDE's either, I'm launching the IDE's through anaconda virtual environment but I thought this should make no difference as its the same environment is where I'm successfully expecting my scripts from the terminal.

Comment: @Zizi96, can you run `env | grep 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'` and verify that it looks as you expect?  If you do not see what you expect you can edit your .bashrc file so it matches what you expect and then source your .bash_profile so your environment is refreshed with the changes you made in .bashrc

Comment: @j_b : Wouldn't `printenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH` be simpler?

Comment: @Zizi96 : If you get through the IDE an **interactive** shell, i.e. a command prompt, it is an interactive bash. If you just have a script be executed and don't get any command prompt, it is likely a **non-interactive** shell, unless you configure it explicitly differently. If you are unsure, do a `echo $-` in your script. You will get a bunch of characters printed. If one of the characters is the letter _i_, the shell is interactive; otherwise it is not.

Comment: @Zizi96: You also did not specify, how you launched the IDE. If the environment of the process, from which you start the IDE, already contains the correct LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it is of course inherited through your IDE up to your bash, and you don't have to care anymore about interactivitiy.